# Bouncycastle embed dll in my c # dll to operate in vb6

Tags: c#, dll, vb6, bouncycastle

I was wondering if I could get help with my C# DLL in VB6, because when I compile my DLL it compiles two DLLs, one is bouncycastle.dll and other MyLibrary.dll. After registering my DLL, I run my code and I get the error:

> "Can not load file or assembly Org.BouncyCastle ....".

Could someone guide me?

Thank you and sorry for my English! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I add the reference in the command line with command "csc.exe".

I leave my solution in case someone serves you!

```
csc target:module /reference:C:\testvb6\projectCDLL\packages\BouncyCastle\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll C:\testvb6\projectCDLL\test.cs
```

Anyway thank you very much! ;)

Greetings and good luck!